# How to add Tab to Product Edit Page in Nopcommerce Admin Side?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am new to nopcommerce & I am developing one module in which i want to add my own tab to Product Edit tabs when I install & enable my module. But, I don't know how to do it.

Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 4):

You can use **IConsumer** interface and handle **AdminTabStripCreated** event

```
public class MyPlugin : BasePlugin, IConsumer<AdminTabStripCreated>
```

and implement it like

```
public void HandleEvent(AdminTabStripCreated eventMessage)
{        
    if (eventMessage.TabStripName == "product-edit")
    {
        eventMessage.ItemFactory.Add().Text("My new tab").Content("<b>Hello world!</b>");
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add references to **Nop.Core**, **Nop.Services**, **Nop.Web.Framework** and **Telerik.Web.Mvc**

Comment: That is your function to fill in the desired HTML as string, you can just as well do **.Content("<b>Hello world</b>")**

Comment: i actually don't understand how to get because .Content function is also not there. I just get GetHashCode() & GetType().

Comment: Edited answer to simplify the implementation and added additional info. Should be straight forward now.

Comment: Thanks It will help me a lot. Now can say that how to Load my View instead of .Content("Hello World");

Comment: Hey using this way the tab is created in my tab, but now i want to fire some action or call some method of my controller while we click on that created tab. How is this possible?